# Group data for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yDsf.png

| year | month | no_of_people | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | 1 | Overall | 8 |
| 2005 | 2 | Overall | 5.0 |
| 2005 | 3 | Overall | 2.7 |
| 2005 | 4 | Overall | 4.1 |
| 2005 | 5 | Overall | 6.8 |
| 2005 | 6 | Overall | 5.2 |
| 2005 | 7 | Overall | 4.7 |
| 2005 | 8 | Overall | 4.4 |
| 2005 | 9 | Overall | 3.8 |
| 2005 | 10 | Overall | 7 |
| 2005 | 11 | Overall | 4.9 |
| 2005 | 12 | Overall | 6.5 |

My issue lies in essentially calculating the avg of three months (123, 456, etc) and displaying this new value as quarterly average of Q1/2/3/4 (indicating Quarters). Sorry for formatting, but an ideal output would be something like:

| year | quarter | no_of_people | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | Q1 | Overall | xxx |
| 2005 | Q2 | Overall | xxx |

Not sure how to even begin with this query and how to group the months into quarters. Any thanks would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you replace that image with text? Just like your expected output.

Comment: And is that the original data? I mean do you have separate columns for `year` and `month`? Or that's already a result from a different query?

Comment: ```CONCAT('Q', (`month`+2) DIV 3)``` will convert the month number to quarter name, and it can be used for rows grouping.

Comment: @FanoFN This image is from a query of the original dataset, which has more values for sub_housing_type, but I elected to only show Overall as this provides a more concise view. To answer your question, yes, the original dataset has separate columns for year and month, with months 1-12 for each sub_housing_type.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of how the code would look like? I cannot seem to get it to work. @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  `year` YEAR,
  `month` TINYINT,
  sub_housing_type VARCHAR(8),
  `avg` DECIMAL(3,1));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(2005, 1, 'Overall', 90.1),
(2005, 2, 'Overall', 88.9),
(2005, 3, 'Overall', 88.9),
(2005, 4, 'Overall', 90.2),
(2005, 5, 'Overall', 86.8),
(2005, 6, 'Overall', 87),
(2005, 7, 'Overall', 84.8),
(2005, 8, 'Overall', 88.1),
(2005, 9, 'Overall', 88.9),
(2005, 10, 'Overall', 87.5),
(2005, 11, 'Overall', 89.1),
(2005, 12, 'Overall', 83.7);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

```sql
SELECT `year`,
       CONCAT('Q', (`month`+2) DIV 3) `quarter`,
       AVG(`avg`) quarter_avg
FROM test
GROUP BY `year`, `quarter`
ORDER BY `year`, `quarter`;
```

| year | quarter | quarter_avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | Q1 | 89.30000 |
| 2005 | Q2 | 88.00000 |
| 2005 | Q3 | 87.26667 |
| 2005 | Q4 | 86.76667 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kChQx1mS)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `date` column in that table, you can directly use [MySQL QUARTER() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter). However, this will return `1-4` instead of `Q1-Q4`. If you don't have date column, then you can combine `year` and `month` column plus a `01` for "day" value, use `DATE_FORMAT` to make it identifiable as date and use `QUARTER()` on it:

```
SELECT `year`,
       QUARTER(DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS('-',`year`,`month`,'01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) 
       AS Quarter,
      sub_housing_type,
      AVG(`avg`) AS Average
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `year`, Quarter, sub_housing_type
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Nz9WsGZ)